# Format Date in VueJS. Back-end to front-end

Tags: date, vue.js, format

So, I need to format a date coming from the back-end into the front-end.
I have a table:

```
    <vue-good-table
    :columns="columns"
    :rows="formatedItems"
    :paginate="true"
    :lineNumbers="true">

<script>
    export default {
        components: {
          Datepicker
        },
            data(){
                return {
            DatePickerFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                    items: [],
            columns: [
                        {
                            label: 'Number',
                            field: 'number',
                            type: 'String',
                            filterable: true,
                            placeholder: 'Number'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Identification number',
                            field: 'identNumber',
                            type: 'String',
                            filterable: true,
                            placeholder: 'Identification number'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Name',
                            field: 'name',
                            type: 'String',
                            filterable: true,
                            placeholder: 'Name'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Code',
                            field: 'code',
                            type: 'String',
                            filterable: true,
                            placeholder: 'Code'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'From',
                            field: 'dateFrom',
                            type: 'String',
                            filterable: true,
                            placeholder: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'To',
                            field: 'dateTo',
                            type: 'String',
                            filterable: true,
                            placeholder: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Last change',
                            field: 'dateChanged',
                            type: 'String',
                            filterable: true,
                            placeholder: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
                        },
                        {},
                        {}
                    ],
                    fields : {
                        "Number": "number",
                        "Identification numer": "identNumber",
                        "Name": "name",
                        "Code": "code",
                        "From": "dateFrom",
                        "To": "dateTo",
                        "Last Change": "dateChanged"
                    },
                    json_meta: [
                        [{
                        "key": "charset",
                        "value": "utf-8"
                        }]
                    ]
                }
            },
    computed: {
      formatedItems () {
        if (!this.items || this.items.length === 0) return []
        return this.rows.map(item => {
          return {
            ...items,
            dateFrom: moment(item.dateFrom).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
            dateTo: moment(item.dateTo).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
            dateChanged: moment(item.dateChanged).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
          }
        })
      }
    }
</script>
```

Is this the correct code segment? Because I can't get it working for some reason?

Upon hitting the "search" button the data comes from the back-end and vizualize in the table. However, the date format right now is 1554163200000. How I can make it and format it in dd/mm/yyyy?

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at s.formattedItems (eoriTable.vue:231)
    at xt.get (vue.esm.js:3142)
    at xt.evaluate (vue.esm.js:3249)
    at s.formattedItems (vue.esm.js:3507)
    at s.render (eoriTable.vue?d724:1)
    at s.A._render (vue.esm.js:4544)
    at s.<anonymous> (vue.esm.js:2788)
    at xt.get (vue.esm.js:3142)
    at xt.run (vue.esm.js:3219)
    at Lt (vue.esm.js:2981)
JA @ vue.esm.js:1741
```

That's the error when I build it. When I change :rows: formattedItems to items (which was the default value) everything is fine it renders but the date is not formatted.

Comment: use moment.js..

Comment: Yeah, but technically how could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and computed properties

```
import moment from 'moment'

....
computed: {
  formatedItems () {
    if (!this.items || this.items.length === 0) return []
    return this.items.map(item => {
      return {
        ...item,
        dateFrom: moment(item.dateFrom).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
        dateTo: moment(item.dateTo).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
        dateChanged: moment(item.dateChanged).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
      }
    })
  }
}
```

and in your component

```
<vue-good-table
:columns="columns"
:rows="formatedItems"
:paginate="true"
:lineNumbers="true">
```

Another option is using [table-row slot](https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table#custom-row-template) of vue-good-table

Comment: I am not very aware of the syntax here. The 'computed', should it be in methods? And "...items" should I change it?

Comment: I have 4 more properties in columns:[] which are identification number, number, name and code if this makes a change?

Comment: Computed properties if different and is outside of methods https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: ...items is ES6 syntax for copy an object. It will copy all attribute of an object, you don't need to do it manually. It's similar with return `Object.assign(items, {
        dateFrom: moment(item.dateFrom).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
        dateTo: moment(item.dateTo).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
        dateChanged: 
       moment(item.dateChanged).format('DD/MM/YYYY')
})` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: Nope, when I hit the search button, it doesn't render absolute no information at all. Maybe the property items shouldn't be changed to formattedItems?

Comment: Updated the first post again. And for some reason in the computed method dateFrom, dateTo and dateChanged are unresolved variables.

Comment: I updated my answer, it should be `return this.items.map(item => {`instead of `return this.rows.map(item => {`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Is there a way I can check if the date is null, just to display empty string or something like that in order to not return Invalid date?